# Adding to %TIME% variable in windows cmd script

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd

I realize that this could probably be done easier in any number of other scripting languages but started to do it quick in cmd and now Im curious.

Looking to start a process at an offset to the time that another process started.  Lets say 5 minutes to keep it simple.  Is there a way to add to the %TIME% variable?

For instance:

```
start /b foo.exe
at %TIME% + 5 minutes bar.exe
```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 14):

I just typed `set/?` and discovered cmd is much better than old bat... :-)

```
set h=%TIME:~0,2%
set m=%TIME:~3,2%
set/a m2="m+5"
set t2=%h%:%m2%
set t2
```

Obviously, you can get 62 minutes, etc., I let you do the extra math... :-D

Comment: When `m` starts with `0`, it expects an octal number, so `08` and `09` are invalid and parsed as zero. `set/a m2="9+1"` => `10`, but `set/a m2="09+1"` => *Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).*

Comment: The workaround for the above is to do `set/a m2="1m-100+5"` (or `%%100`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the extra math:

```
:: Get an offset of 1 minute from the current time, accounting for edge cases
set hr=%TIME:~0,2%
set /a mn=%TIME:~3,2%+1
:: check minutes; greater than 60? add n/60 to hour, n%60 to mins
if %mn% geq 60 set /a hr=hr+mn/60 && set /a mn=mn%%60
if %hr% geq 24 set /a h=0
:: pad zeros if necessary
if %mn% leq 9 set mn=0%mn%
if %hr% leq 9 set hr=0%hr%
```

Comment: if %hr% leq 9 set hr=0%hr:~1,1%

Answer (score 2):

2 PhiLho

**thanks**

My bath code:

```
set h=%TIME:~0,2%
set m=%TIME:~3,2%
set s=%TIME:~6,2%
set time=%h%_%m%_%s%
mkdir c:\test\%time%
move c:\test\*.* c:\test\%time%
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\RAR" a -ep c:\test\%time%\ -agDD-MM-YY_hh-mm-ss c:\test\%time%\*.* -zc:\arhiv\HEADERS.TXT
move c:\test\%time%\*.rar c:\arhiv\
rmdir c:\test\%time% /S /Q
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        @echo off
        :: START USAGE  ==================================================================
        ::SET THE NICETIME 
        :: SET NICETIME=BOO
        :: CALL GetNiceTime.cmd 

        :: ECHO NICETIME IS %NICETIME%

        :: echo nice time is %NICETIME%
        :: END USAGE  ==================================================================

        echo set hhmmsss
        :: this is Regional settings dependant so tweak this according your current settings
        for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ('echo %time%') do set hhmmsss=%%a%%b%%c 
        ::DEBUG ECHO hhmmsss IS %hhmmsss%
        ::DEBUG PAUSE
        echo %yyyymmdd%
            :: this is Regional settings dependant so tweak this according your current settings
        for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%D in ('echo %DATE%') do set  yyyymmdd=%%F%%E%%D
        ::DEBUG ECHO yyyymmdd IS %yyyymmdd%
        ::DEBUG PAUSE


        set NICETIME=%yyyymmdd%_%hhmmsss%
        ::DEBUG echo THE NICETIME IS %NICETIME%

        ::DEBUG PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

copy.cmd:

```
set hr=%TIME:~0,2%
if %hr% leq 9 set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
set mydate=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%-%hr%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%
copy file.txt file-%mydate%.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended the "bath code" a little bit:

```
echo ----- time -----
echo %time%
set _hh=%time:~0,2%
set _mm=%time:~3,2%
set _ss=%time:~6,2%
set __time=%_hh%%_mm%%_ss%
echo _%__time%_
echo ----- time -----
echo:
echo ----- date -----
echo %date%
set _Y=%date:~0,4%
set _M=%date:~5,2%
set _D=%date:~8,2%
set __date=%_Y%%_M%%_D%
echo _%__date%_
echo ----- date -----
pause
```

Outputs *205146* for %__time%

Outputs *20180613* for %__date%

Comment: this fails for other date localizations such as the european 13/12/1234 format