# How to fetch time in a batch file and use time as string

Tags: time, batch-file, path

I want to fetch the current time and create a folder with the name of the time.
How can i fetch the time into a variable?

```
SET %%DESTINATIONDIRROOT = "I:\directory\"
SET %%DESTINATIONDIRSEPERATOR = "\"
SET %%DESTINATIONDIR = TIME


for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b IN (`DIR /B /S /A "C:\RandomTestFiles\*.*"`) DO @(
   XCOPY  /Y "%%~b" %%DESTINATIONDIRROOT%%DESTINATIONDIR%%DESTINATIONDIRSEPERATOR
)
```

Comment: Ooh - do be very careful. The syntax you've posted is doomed to fail. Spaces before and after the `=` in a `set` statement are included in the variable name and the value assigned. Quotes too although `set "var=value"` is used to set `var` to `value` even if there are trailing spaces after the `"value"`. `var` is a variable NAME, `%var%` is the CONTENT of a variable. `%%x`, where `x` is a letter and is case-sensitive refers to a metavariable - the loop-control in a `FOR` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt these if you have XP Pro and above.  They do not suffer from changes in regional settings and date/time variables, and are padded properly.

:: timestamp YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set dt=%dt:~0,8%_%dt:~8,6%
echo %dt%
pause
```

:: timestamp YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set dt=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%_%dt:~8,2%-%dt:~10,2%-%dt:~12,2%
echo %dt%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This **m**akes a **d**irectory called `yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm`:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set bdate=%%c-%%b-%%a)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set btime=%%a-%%b)
md %bdate%_%btime%
```

For European-style dates (dd-mm-yyyy), use `bdate=%%a-%%b-%%c`.

For American-style dates (mm-dd-yyyy), use `bdate=%%b-%%a-%%c`.

<sub>**NB:** A machine locale of `en-US` would probably reverse the above 2 scenarios.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Consider %DATE% and %TIME%:

SET someVar = %TIME%

Do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1254897/431415

Comment: A folder cannot contain `:` or `/` in its name.

Comment: He asked how to fetch time into a variable - but I have linked to a direct example of what he wants to do, since there are constraints (as you mentioned).