# Increment access time of file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to increment the access time of a file by a given number of hours, e.g. 12 hours.

I found a way to hack it using [Unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) `touch.exe` tool and calculate the new date manually:

```
touch.exe -a -t MMDDhhmmCCYY my_file.txt
```

However, I would like to automatize this without having to enter the new date manually. So here are my questions:

1. How can I retrieve the access time of a file in DOS?
2. How can I increment it?
3. How can I put that together into a script/batch-file?
4. Or are there better approaches?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've got it tagged for Powershell:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem testfile.txt
$file.lastwritetime

$file.LastWriteTime = ($file.LastWriteTime).AddHours(12)
$file.LastWriteTime

Tuesday, November 19, 2013 5:27:18 PM
Wednesday, November 20, 2013 5:27:18 AM
```

Comment: This won't work for more than one file, since you are using the `Get-ChildItem` it is just matter of changing the filter to save more than one file in the $file variable. This is how it may be done for more files. `$file = Get-ChildItem -path \temp -filter *.log;
$file | foreach { 
 $_.LastWriteTime = ($_.LastWriteTime).AddHours(12);
 $_.LastWriteTime
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last access time in batch using this example:

```
for /f %%A in ( ' dir /b /TA "c:\test.txt" ' ) do set accesstime=%%~tA
echo %accesstime%
```

but then to increment it correctly, you are going to have to do something like this:
[Adding to %TIME% variable in windows cmd script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301108/adding-to-time-variable-in-windows-cmd-script)

And account for jumping dates, etc.

In powershell, you can read and write the LastAccessTime of a file like so:

```
$file = Get-Item "c:\test.txt"
$file.LastAccessTime = ($file.LastAccessTime).AddHours(12)
```