# Automatic Server Inquery Clasic ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have an admin system where I can send emails with my lead info in it.

What I'm trying to achieve is an auto command where 10 minutes after I sent the email another email will be sent. The page with the action of sending the second email is ready, but how do I "activate" the action without logging into the system and do it manually?

I'm using IIS w. Classic ASP.

Comment: Classic ASP doesn't lend itself to this type of task well, a better approach would be to build a service to handle this task. As I don't know any more about your environment can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a batch file to schedule this task.

Run batch file from asp http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/442265-asp-run-command-line

The batch command for scheduled tasks [Make server automatic run asp-script every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383165/make-server-automatic-run-asp-script-every-day)

Here is how to add 5 minutes (or 10 minutes) to current time [Adding to %TIME% variable in windows cmd script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301108/adding-to-time-variable-in-windows-cmd-script)

I let you read and combine all that.

Comment: This can work but also extremely flimsy approach. Batch isn't the only option though, you could just set-up a schedule task using scheduler in windows that runs a VBScript that mimics the e-mail send used in the Classic ASP page for example. Still not ideal but not as archaic.

Comment: The answer work for the guy's question, if you have better solution so please share

Comment: Lankymart has explained his reasons, your response was a little acerbic.  One option, depending on the version of IIS and SQL server (probably the reason why Lanky isn't going too far into this) is to use SQL Server Mail capabilities. The answer would border more on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) territory.

Comment: There a lots of different approaches all as opinion based as the next which makes this question a bad fit for SO. Ideally the OP should clarify their environment more *(OS, Web Server, DB etc)* and detail what they have tried so far.